# Verb suggestion: wounding by constant contact

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there an *esoteric* or *literary* verb that describes the process of causing a progressively deepening wound as a result of continuous contact with a sharp restraint such as a chain around the neck/ankles or a barbed wire.

I can only think of *chafing*, but I suppose chafing suggests light scraping. I would like to evoke the perception of a deep cut in the flesh, resultant of recurring contact.

Comment: How are we defining *literary* and *esoteric* here?

Comment: There is the term _ligature marks_ that medical examiners use to mean the indelible cut marks left after being tied by rope or wire.

Comment: @Spagirl By _literary_ and _esoteric_ I meant words you wouldn't generally find in everyday speech, but rather in prose or poem.

Comment: Bind or girt might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Abrading* [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/abrade)
*Lacerating* [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lacerate)
Both words are used in medicine, but, differently than in general writing. They both mean  what the question requires, with *lacerating* being a stronger term.

A *lacerating* chain would cut whatever it was wrapped around by friction.

*Serrating*  could be used, but is posibly more medical than the other two, as it isn't used much in general writing[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/serrating), but good for barbed wire wounds.

*Gashing* does not seem to have a medical meaning at all, so it could work:

> With every move, the chain gashed deeper

My guess is *gashing* may be most appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

There is a word for this, especially in equine medicine. It is called *galling*.

Per *Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary*, 2nd Edition (p. 483), a general definition of a *gall* is:

> a sore caused by chafing; said commonly of horses

There are a couple of other related definitions in the same dictionary:

> *girth gall* (p. 499): a skin abrasion on the chest just behind the elbow of a horse caused by pressure or movement of the girth while being ridden. Caused by sharp edges of the girth, girth adjusted too tightly or too loosely or a poor conformation of the horse.
>
> *saddle sore, saddle gall* (p. 1005): a pressure sore caused by bad riding technique or more commonly a badly fitting or poorly stuffed saddle.

As for in human medicine, *Dorland's Illustrated Medical Dictionary*, 28th Edition, has one definition of *gall* as follows (p. 673):

> a localized swelling or skin sore caused by friction.

As for the verb form of the word, *gall* is both a transitive and intransitive verb (see this entry on [FreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gall))

> v.t.
>   to make sore by rubbing; chafe severely: *The saddle galled the horse's back.*
>
> v.i.
>   to be or become chafed.

Here are a couple of examples of gall being used in a sentence [from the Wordnik entry for *galled*:](https://www.wordnik.com/words/galled)

> His flesh was galled by many days of contact with the haul-rope.
>
> His shoulders and chest, galled by the pack-straps, made him think, and for the first time with understanding, of the horses he had seen on city streets.

Answer (score 2):

If looking for more esoteric terms I'd suggest looking for those which you can use in a figurative rather than literal sense.

A [harrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrow_(tool)) is a spiked frame for breaking up soil. if this is analogous to the spiked barbed wire you could say that ***the wire harrowed his flesh***.

To keep that agricultural theme you could say that the bonds '***like a [scratch-plough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ard_(plough)), had opened a deep furrow' in his flesh***.
Failing that you could consider [Excoriate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excoriate) '.
*to strip off or remove the skin from*, which

> first appeared in English in the 15th century, comes from
>   "excoriatus," the past participle of the Late Latin verb excoriare,
>   meaning "to strip off the hide."